# Is there a way to include the HREF in the CSS Selector

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Say I wanted to click w3schools.com (top left corner) on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp 
So something like this..

```
a[href*="w3schools"]
```

More specifically..

```
div.w3-container.top > a[href*="w3schools"][.w3schools-logo]
```

Something like....    `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.w3-container.top > a[href*="w3schools"][.w3schools-logo]")`This does not seem to work in Selenium.

Is what I am asking possible?  Using   `a[href*="w3schools"]` would greatly narrow down the CSS selectors of HREF without having to resort to any other elements of a page.

Comment: Have you tried other selectors? `a[href="//www.w3schools.com"]` or `a[href$="w3schools.com"]`

Comment: Your selector is also plain out wrong, should be `div.w3-container.top > a[href*="w3schools"].w3schools-logo`

Comment: @minseong I tend to get for:
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.w3-container.top > a[href*="w3schools"].w3schools-logo")
                                                
SyntaxError: invalid syntax with a ^ below the s "w3schools"

Comment: Maybe selenium doesn't support that kind of selector. Look at my first comment, try those.

Comment: @minseong I believe you are correct.  Thanks for your help.  The other selectors do work perfectly :). I will mark your answer in 3 minutes when I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've told me it looks like an error in your python rather than an error in your CSS.

This is your current code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.w3schools-logo[href*‌​="w3schools"]")
```

Change it to this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.w3schools-logo[href*‌​='w3schools']")
```

Essentially, use single-quotes (`'`) in your CSS.

---

Try one of these selectors:

```
div.w3-container.top > a[href*='w3schools']
div.w3-container.top > a
div.w3-container.top > a.w3schools-logo
div.w3-container.top > a.w3schools-logo[href*='w3schools']
```

Your selector had something like `a[href*='w3schools'][.w3schools-logo]` which is just incorrect CSS.

If you want to combine a class selector with an attribute selector it should look like:

```
a.w3schools-logo[href*='w3schools']
```

Comment: I am using Python 3 and a.w3schools-logo[href*="w3schools"] or driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.w3schools-logo[href*="w3schools"]") does not seem to work.  It keeps underlining w3schools besdie Href*= and saying unresolved reference.

Comment: @Hector77 use this python code: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.w3schools-logo[href*‌​="w3schools"]')` instead of your current one. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is almost correct- you just need to replace double quotes with single quotes:

```
href*‌​‌​="w3schools" -> href*‌​‌​='w3schools'
```

and specify `class` attribute node type explicitly in predicate:

```
[.w3schools-logo] -> [class='w3schools-logo']
```

So below should work well:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.w3-container.top > a[href*='w3schools'][class='w3schools-logo']")
```